# Buscar con una lista en un diccionario en python

Tags: python, diccionarios

Buen día

Tengo el siguiente diccionario
Clases={'Grupo 1': 'Leche y derivados', 'Grupo 2': 'Leche y derivados', 'Grupo 3': 'Patatas, legumbres, frutos secos', 'Grupo 4': 'Verduras y Hortalizas', 'Grupo 5': 'Frutas'}

Necesito buscar esta lista, grupo=['Grupo 2', 'Grupo 4'] en ese diccionario.

La salida seria una lista con lo que encontró en el diccionario, por ejemplo, ['Leche y derivados', 'Verduras y Hortalizas']

No he podido encontrar la solución. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con comprensión de listas:

```
Clases={'Grupo 1': 'Leche y derivados', 'Grupo 2': 'Leche y derivados', 'Grupo 3': 'Patatas, legumbres, frutos secos', 'Grupo 4': 'Verduras y Hortalizas', 'Grupo 5': 'Frutas'}
grupos=['Grupo 2', 'Grupo 4']

lista = [Clases[grupo] for grupo in grupos]

print(lista)
```

El `for grupo in grupos` recorre la lista de grupos, asignando cada elemento a la variable `grupo`. Esta variable se usa para recuperar la descripción del grupo en `Clases[grupo]`.

Answer (score 1):

Viendo tu código se me ocurre la siguiente forma de hacerlo. Necesitamos dos bucles `for`

```
Clases={'Grupo 1': 'Leche y derivados', 'Grupo 2': 'Leche y derivados', 'Grupo 3': 'Patatas, legumbres, frutos secos', 'Grupo 4': 'Verduras y Hortalizas', 'Grupo 5': 'Frutas'}
grupo = ['Grupo 2','Grupo 4']
solucion = []
for i in Clases:
    for j in grupo:
        if i == j:
            solucion.append(Clases[i])


print(solucion)
```

Explicación:
El primer bucle lo que hace es recorrer el diccionario, y el segundo recorre los grupos a buscar. Ahora solo quedaría añadir la condición, por lo que si el elemento de `grupo` es una `key` del diccionario `Clases`, nos imprima el `value` de esa `key`

Ya por último sólo queda añadir el resultado a la lista `solucion`

Un saludo.

Espero que te haya solucionado la duda.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias por las dos respuestas, quisiera agregar que las dos respuestas dan como resultado `lista=['Leche y derivados', 'Verduras y Hortalizas']`. Posteriormente, se me solicitaba que entregara esta lista de la siguiente manera `lista=['Leche y derivados, verduras y hortalizas']`. Después de darle muchas vueltas me funciono lo siguiente: `lista=[(', '.join(lista)).capitalize()]`.

¿Es esa una forma eficiente o existirá otra mejor?

Gracias de nuevo.